# Heartbeat explanation

Tags: servicestack

i'm using servicestack in my server application.
This is the code to start the service:

```
        public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        LogManager.LogFactory = new KCServiceObjects.ServiceLoggerFactory();
        ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

        Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature()
        {
            HeartbeatInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
            NotifyChannelOfSubscriptions = true,

        });
        Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());

        container.Register<IServerEvents>(c => new MemoryServerEvents());
        notifier = new FrontendMessages(container.Resolve<IServerEvents>(), broker);
        container.Register(c => notifier);
        container.Register<IWebServiceEventManager>(c =>
                    new WebServiceEventManager(broker));

        SetConfig(new HostConfig
        {  
            DebugMode = true, 
            DefaultContentType = MimeTypes.Json,
            EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove(Feature.Html),
            GlobalResponseHeaders =
            {
                { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
                { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE" },
                { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type" },
            },
        });
    }
```

This is .NET client:

```
                clientEvents = new ServerEventsClient(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/", sIP, 20001), "messages");
            client = (IServiceClient)(clientEvents.ServiceClient);

            clientEvents.Resolver = resolver;
            clientEvents.RegisterReceiver<GlobalReceiver>();
            clientEvents.OnConnect = (e) =>
            {
                var msg = JsonObject.Parse(e.Json);
                ConnectionInfo = new ServerEventConnect
                {
                    HeartbeatIntervalMs = DefaultHeartbeatMs,
                    IdleTimeoutMs = DefaultIdleTimeoutMs,
                }.Populate(e, msg);

                ConnectionInfo.Id = msg.Get("id");
                ConnectionInfo.HeartbeatUrl = msg.Get("heartbeatUrl");
                ConnectionInfo.HeartbeatIntervalMs = msg.Get<long>("heartbeatIntervalMs");
                ConnectionInfo.IdleTimeoutMs = msg.Get<long>("idleTimeoutMs");
                ConnectionInfo.UnRegisterUrl = msg.Get("unRegisterUrl");
                ConnectionInfo.UserId = msg.Get("userId");
                ConnectionInfo.DisplayName = msg.Get("displayName");
                ConnectionInfo.ProfileUrl = msg.Get("profileUrl");


            };
```

At the moment the heartbeat is not working, but i'm sure i've missed something in my code. Looking at logs, server sends a STOP() and then a START().
How must be implemented in c#? Does the client have to send a message to server every n seconds?

Thanks to all
Leonardo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

If you want to change the Interval, you also need to change the IdleTimeout, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature {
    HeartbeatInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
    IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180),
});
```

You don't need to set `NotifyChannelOfSubscriptions = true`, it's the default.

You don't need to register `MemoryServerEvents`, it's the default:

```
//container.Register<IServerEvents>(c => new MemoryServerEvents());
```

Never populate the `ConnectionInfo` yourself like you're doing in the `OnConnect` handler, it could break the behavior if done incorrectly.

Instead of adding CORS `GlobalResponseHeaders`, just register the `CorsFeature` plugin, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature());
```